# Page counter with Luebeck theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, page-numbering

I'm trying to create a page/slide counter in the lower left corner of my presentation. I'm using the following themes

```
\usetheme{Luebeck}  
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

Can I insert a counter? In the default version of these themes, there is no counter included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fill]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot} \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\author{(Author)}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, fast and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Newby1 Thanks for accepting my answer, but please also upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting).